# sum column based on level selected in column header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.dataframe and it looks like this. Note column names represent level.

```
   df
             PC        0     1     2    3 
       0    PC_1      0.74  0.25  0.1  0.0   
       1    PC_1      0.72  0.26  0.1  0.1 
       2    PC_2      0.80  0.18  0.2  0.0
       3    PC_3      0.79  0.19  0.1  0.1
```

I want to create another 4 columns next to the existing columns and shift the values based on the condition assigned.

For example: if level =1, df should look like this:

```
       df
             PC        0     1     2    3    0_1     1_1         2_1  3_1
       0    PC_1      0.74  0.25  0.1  0.0   0.0   (0.72+0.25)   0.1  0.0
       1    PC_1      0.72  0.26  0.1  0.1   0.0   (0.72+0.26)   0.1  0.1 
       2    PC_2      0.80  0.18  0.2  0.0   0.0   (0.80+0.18)   0.2  0.0
       3    PC_3      0.79  0.19  0.1  0.1   0.0   (0.79+0.19)   0.1  0.0
```

If level=3,

```
       df
             PC        0     1     2    3    0_3   1_3  2_3   3_3
       0    PC_1      0.74  0.25  0.1  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  sum(0.74+0.25+0.1+0.0)
       1    PC_1      0.72  0.26  0.1  0.1   0.0   0.0  0.0  sum(0.72+0.26+0.1+0.1)
       2    PC_2      0.80  0.18  0.2  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  sum(0.80+0.18+0.20+0.0)
       3    PC_3      0.79  0.19  0.1  0.1   0.0   0.0  0.0  sum(0.79+0.19+0.1+0.1)
```

I don't know how to solve the problem and am looking for help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `'PC'` to the index to make things easier. We zero everything before your column, cumsum up to the column, and keep everything as is after your column.

```
df = df.set_index('PC')

def add_sum(df, level):
    i = df.columns.get_loc(level)
    df_add = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=df.columns[:i]), 
                         df.cumsum(1).iloc[:, i], 
                         df.iloc[:, i+1:]], 
                        axis=1)
                .add_suffix(f'_{level}'))

    return pd.concat([df, df_add], axis=1)
```

---

```
add_sum(df, '1')  # 1 if columns labels are int
         0     1    2    3  0_1   1_1  2_1  3_1
PC                                             
PC_1  0.74  0.25  0.1  0.0    0  0.99  0.1  0.0
PC_1  0.72  0.26  0.1  0.1    0  0.98  0.1  0.1
PC_2  0.80  0.18  0.2  0.0    0  0.98  0.2  0.0
PC_3  0.79  0.19  0.1  0.1    0  0.98  0.1  0.1

add_sum(df, '3')
         0     1    2    3  0_3  1_3  2_3   3_3
PC                                             
PC_1  0.74  0.25  0.1  0.0    0    0    0  1.09
PC_1  0.72  0.26  0.1  0.1    0    0    0  1.18
PC_2  0.80  0.18  0.2  0.0    0    0    0  1.18
PC_3  0.79  0.19  0.1  0.1    0    0    0  1.18
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote *based on level selected in column header* in the title,
I understand that:

- there is no "external" *level* variable,
- the *level* (how many columns to sum) results just from
  the source column name.

So the task is actually to "concatenate" your both expected results (you presented only how to compute column *1_1* and *3_1*) and compute other
new columns the same way.

The solution to do it is surprisingly concise.
Run the following one-liner:

```
df = df.join(df.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(axis=1)
    .rename(lambda name: str(name) + '_1', axis=1))
```

Details:

- `df.iloc[:, 1:]` - Take all rows, starting from column 1 (column
  numbers from 0).
- `cumsum(axis=1)` - Compute cumulative sum, horizontally.
- `rename(..., axis=1)` - Rename columns.
- `lambda name: str(name) + '_1'` - Lambda function to compute new
  column name.
- The result so far - new columns.
- `df = df.join(...)` - Join with the original DataFrame and save the
  result back under *df*.